# multiple actions (CRUD) in one servlet java

Tags: java, json, servlets, url-routing, crud

I want to use one servlet for four action CRUD. following servlet works well for adding data by following url

http://localhost:8080/mobsurvey/register-company/?companyname=xyz&email=abc@abc.com&username=user&password=pass&description=xyz

response in json like
{"result":"true","lastId":2}

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.*; 
import com.saffroze.Event;




public class CompanyRegister extends HttpServlet {
Connection conn=null;
public CompanyRegister() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    conn = Dbhelper.getConnection();
    //      creatBookManagerTable();
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {


    String companyname = req.getParameter("companyname");
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    String usr = req.getParameter("username");
    String pwd = req.getParameter("password");
    String description = req.getParameter("description");



    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    String sql = "insert into company("+ "name,"+ "email,"+ "username,"+ "password,"+ "description)"+" values(?,?,?,?,?)";      

    try {

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        //String insertDataSql="insert into company(name,email,username,password,description) values('" + companyname + "','" + email + "','" + usr + "','" + pwd + "','" + description + "');";

        //Statement stmt;

        pstmt.setString(1,companyname);
        pstmt.setString(2,email);
        pstmt.setString(3,usr);
        pstmt.setString(4,pwd);
        pstmt.setString(5,description);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //resp.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet keys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();  

        keys.next();  
        int id = 0; 

        id = keys.getInt(1);  

        keys.close();  



        if(id>0){

            Event obj = new Event("true",id);

            resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(obj));     
        }else
        {
            int emptyid=0;
            Event obj = new Event("false",emptyid);


            resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(obj));


        }

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**I want use same servlet for other action like delete , view etc by  url(it should use only one above servlet for actions)**

http://localhost:8080/mobsurvey/view-company/?company_id=1

should response it data in json

**currently web.xml**

```
  <display-name>mobsurvey</display-name>
  <servlet>
 <servlet-name>CompanyRegister Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.saffroze.CompanyRegister</servlet-class>

 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>CompanyRegister Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/register-company/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

I am newbie in java-servlet

Any Suggestions ?
Thank You.

Comment: and what's your question? You wanted comment on your approach. OR wanted to know how to add delete/view functionality. Or how to map various URLs?

Comment: @Nishant. I wanted use one servlet for all related actions to that servlet.. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some extra information in your URL.
Like parameters

```
?action=edit&id=1
```

And in your servlet you can use the action parameter for decision making

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
if(action.equal(...) { /* Your logic here */ }
```

Or you can implement your own dispatcher to route request with URL like

```
company/edit/1
```

Or you can override the service() method to support PUT, DELETE, ... and make your servlet RESTful. But browsers' support for those methods [is not very good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671242/how-do-you-send-anything-beside-get-and-post-from-browser-to-your-restful-app).

Comment: @hope_is_grim.Thanks for your reply. I am building survey app which may be scale in future. is this better approach or any other suggestion ?

Comment: If it doesn't have to be servlet, I think RESTful Web Service is a better solution. You can start by finding some tutorial about creating and working with RESTful Web service.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question really. There are several ways to do what you want to achieve, one of them is what @hope_is_grim has put forth. Using a Single Servlet for a number of CRUD operations is not a scalable solution, IMHO. I've been there, done that and later switched to pure RESTful web services using libraries like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). It makes the code maintainable, scalable and readable. The sooner you opt, the better.

Useful thread

- [Java WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483764/java-webservice)